# Why do _some_ -phile words have sexual context if phileo means friendship love?

Tags: meaning, suffixes

Lots of words ending with -phile have a sexual context, yet phileo is a friendship love which has nothing to do with sexual context. Why is that? Is there an innocent, pure, friendly suffix that can be used with the meaning "lover" and not "luster"?

Comment: There is one vote to close as "unclear what you are asking".  I find the question clear.  The OP is asking about a suffix that connotes intense friendship, friendship so close that it is love, but with no sexual undertones or overtones or sexual content at all.  A friendship between equals, so it isn't doesn't have parent-child content either.  Surely everyone has a few such friendships. OP -- if I am wrong, please clarify.  And feel free to incorporate whatever you want of this in your Q.

Comment: Would you have more than one example?

Comment: I think the distinctions between "philea," "eros," "agape" etc. were probably not as clear-cut in actual spoken Ancient Greek as they are made out to be. See this Wikipedia article: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_words_for_love "as with other languages, it has been historically difficult to separate the meanings of these words" "in [Nichomachean Ethics]  philos denotes a general type of love, used for love between family, between friends, a desire or enjoyment of an activity, as well as between lovers"

Comment: @ab2 I have to confess that I am the close-voter. How many words ending with -phile have sexual connotation? I don't think "bibliophile", musicophile, etc. have it. I think the question needs more examples with more clear context.

Comment: @Rathony Good point.  Also, I don't think the Quakers were thinking sexually when they named Philadelphia.

Comment: Here are some examples: "paraphilia", "necrophilia", "pedophilia". Those are definitely sexual. Why isn't it "parasex" or "necrosex" or "pedosex"? "Pedophilia" should have the meaning of the love of cherishing, not what today's evil people do to children. If I made a neologism with "-philia" to express fandom or friendship, I'd get trolled with conspiracy theories watched by many people to think that I'm a sexual deviant or something while I just want to say "friend of-" or "liker of-" or "someone who feels so happy and excited when doing-".

Comment: @Foxcat385, I think that your question simplifies down to "why have some -phile words been used in the mainstream as sexual terms and others not", to which I'm not sure you'll find a satisfactory answer. What I do know is that I hear people coining new -philes on a regular basis (less frequently new -philia) and none of the listeners or readers seeming to assume sexual connotations.

Comment: I think a more fruitful line of enquiry, if you can get it through a search engine without having a heart attack, would be to find the first common usages of your sexual -philia. I suspect you'll find that they all come from a single area - probably either the justice system or the medical community - and that someone there set a precedent that was then followed within that sector. Off the top of my head, I can't think of any sexual -philia that are not crimes (at least in most parts of the world) or psychological conditions.

Comment: Another example of the sexualization of the philos root is the term philander. At one time this was a given name meaning "lover of men" in the platonic sense of someone who loves all mankind; there was even a prominent 18th century Episcopalian Bishop named Philander Chase. But the meaning has shifted, so that now it's a verb for male sexual promiscuity with women (despite the definition of 'ander'). Per http://www.behindthename.com/name/philander this change occurred in the 17th century, after which the name fell out of fashion, so that might be a timeframe to look for the shift in general.

Comment: For the same reason that 'love' can denote romantic relationships or the act of merely enjoying something.

Answer (score 4):

Michael Quinion, *Ologies and Isms: Word Beginnings and Endings* (2002) suggests that words taking the suffix -*phile* can be sorted into a number of subgroups within the *philos*-related family:

> **-phile** Also **-phil**, **-philia**, **-phily**, **-philic**, and **-philous**. *Lover of or enthusiast for, having an affinity with a given thing.* {Greek philos, loving.}
>
> Several broad groups are linked within this ending. One set denotes an admirer of the customs, people, or institutions of a country: ***Anglophile***, ***Francophile***, ***Slavophile***, ***Japanophile***. Another marks an enthusiast for the cultural products of a medium (***audiophile***, ***cinephile***, ***videophile***), or for some subject area (***bibliophile***, a lover of books; ***oenophile***, a connoisseur of wines; ***technophile***, a person who is enthusiastic about new technology). It also appears in names for abnormal psychological states: a ***paedophile*** (US ***pedophile***) (Greek *pais*, *paid-*, child, boy) is a person who is sexually attracted to children; a ***zoophile*** (Greek *zoion*, animal) can be a person with a morbid attraction to animals (though it is also used for a micro-organism that attacks animals).

So, according to Quinion, constructions such as *necrophile* are merely a subset of the larger group of possible meanings of *-phile*—a particular subset that refers to attractions based on abnormal psychological states. The existence of such words needn't be seen as casting any kind of sexual shadow over words such as *Russophile*, *acidophile*, and *electrophile*.